# How to store the | in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what will be the best practice for me to use the `|` i.e. do I wrap it in a div class or store it in a span tag? Basically what I want to achieve is the following.

> Ask a question | Privacy | Statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<footer role="contentinfo">
<div class="footer-bottom hidden-print">
<div class="Container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">

<ul class="list list--inline" role="menu" aria-label="Navigation">
<li role="menuitem" aria-label="Ask a question">
<a href="/question" title="Ask a question">Ask a question</a>&nbsp; | 
</li>
<li role="menuitem" aria-label="Privacy">
<a href="/privacy" title="Privacy">Privacy</a>&nbsp; | 
                                        </li>
<li role="menuitem" aria-label="Statement">
<a href="/test" title="Statement">Statement</a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</footer></body>

</html>
```

Please advise.

Comment: or using border-right

Comment: Indeed...no need to use a charcter for this. Style the right border or us a pseudo-element.

Comment: @Sfili_81 What do you mean?

Comment: Please modify answer

Comment: for example setting a border- right to the a tag

Comment: If its a really tough requirement for you to use the "|" character, try putting `&#124;` and see if it works.

Comment: To add more flexibility you can add ::after or ::before pseudo elements like
`::after{ content:'|' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `border-right` with pseudo-selectors for this so you don't have to have the pipe (`|`) in your markup.

**Pseudo-Selectors**

- `:not()` -- exclude what is inside the brackets
- `:first-child` -- first of this type of descendant
- `:last-child` -- last of this type of descendant

*descendant, as in your markup, as `li` is the child (descendant) of `ul`.*

```css
ul[role="menu"].list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li[role="menuitem"]:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

li[role="menuitem"]:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<footer role="contentinfo">
<div class="footer-bottom hidden-print">
<div class="Container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">

  <ul class="list list--inline" role="menu" aria-label="Navigation">
    <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Ask a question">
      <a href="/question" title="Ask a question">Ask a question</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Privacy">
      <a href="/privacy" title="Privacy">Privacy</a> 
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Statement">
      <a href="/test" title="Statement">Statement</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to have special characters at all.

Just use a right-border...

```css
ul {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
list-style:none;
}

li {
padding:0 1em;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
border-right:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<footer role="contentinfo">
  <div class="footer-bottom hidden-print">
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

          <ul class="list list--inline" role="menu" aria-label="Navigation">
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Ask a question">
              <a href="/question" title="Ask a question">Ask a question</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Privacy">
              <a href="/privacy" title="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Statement">
              <a href="/test" title="Statement">Statement</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Alternatively, use a pseudo-element

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 3px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<footer role="contentinfo">
  <div class="footer-bottom hidden-print">
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

          <ul class="list list--inline" role="menu" aria-label="Navigation">
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Ask a question">
              <a href="/question" title="Ask a question">Ask a question</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Privacy">
              <a href="/privacy" title="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-label="Statement">
              <a href="/test" title="Statement">Statement</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```